# Testing for a specific relationship between three variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance

My data consist of 50 measurements of variables A, B, and C.

Prior to looking at my data I am interested in seeing whether A is negatively correlated with both B and C, and whether B and C are positively correlated.

I find that:

cor(A,B) = -0.266 (p=0.056)

cor(A,C) = -0.272 (p=0.051)

cor(B,C) = 0.044 (p=0.754)

using the cor.test() function in R.

Is there a way to test my hypothesis above and generate a corresponding measure of significance?

Would some form of permutation test be appropriate here? If I randomly shuffle the values of A, B, and C many times, and then count the number of instances with correlations equal to or more extreme than my observed correlations.

Comment: if you correct for multiple testing, is that not precisely what you have done?

Comment: Yes, I guess. But is there a way to generate a single measure of significance?

Comment: I can only think of multiple regression with interaction coefficients or mediation analysis but I also have a similar question.